# equivalent to Open GL precision attributes (lowp, mediump, highp) in iOS Metal

Tags: ios, metal

In OpenGL ES it is possible to set precision to uniforms and attributes using lopw/mediump/highp. Is there something like this in Metal?

Answer (score 4):

The metal shading language supports the half data type (see section 2.1 of [the spec](https://developer.apple.com/metal/metal-shading-language-specification.pdf)). It's defined there as:

```
A 16-bit floating-point. The half data type must conform to the IEEE 754 binary16 storage format.
```

This makes it pretty much equivalent to mediump.

There isn't really an equivalent to lowp in metal. However, that's no real loss because I believe that metal capable iOS GPUs don't benefit from lowp anyway and just do any lowp operations at mediump.